# How to multiply in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I'm as new as new gets to writing code with JavaScript, this is actually my first attempt and this is my issue. what I need to do with this form is multiply the input of the Qty box with the input of the Price box and auto populate the Ext box but I can only figure out how to add the totals of Qty and Price and populate that total in the Ext box. Here is the code I am using:

```
function multiply1() {
    var extend1=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "1_value"+i;
        extend1 = extend1 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("extend1").value = extend1;
}
function multiply2() {
    var extend2=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "2_value"+i;
        extend2 = extend2 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("extend2").value = extend2;
}
 function multiply3() {
    var extend3=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "3_value"+i;
        extend3 = extend3 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("extend3").value = extend3;
}
function multiply4() {
    var extend4=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "4_value"+i;
        extend4 = extend4 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("extend4").value = extend4;
}
 function multiply5() {
    var extend5=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "5_value"+i;
        extend5 = extend5 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("extend5").value = extend5;
}
```

Also if you input a total in the qty box it will populate the ext box but should also populate to totals of the ext boxes in the Material Total box which obviously isn't happening the script works to total the ext boxes up and populate the material totals box as u can see by entering a total into any of the ext boxes and it will populate or total into the material total box.

Ok so first I need to multiply the Qty and Price boxes and secondly I need to figure out why this script isn't getting the value from the ext boxes after they are input from the Qty and Price script

```
function summate() {
    var mattotal=0
    for (var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var id = "extend"+i;
        mattotal = mattotal + document.getElementById(id).value*1;
    }
    document.getElementById("mattotal").value = mattotal;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to (...) multiply the input of the Qty box with the input of the Price box and auto populate the Ext box

Firsf off, you are summing the values (`extend1 = extend1 + document.getElementById(id).value*1;`). If you want to multiply them, well, multiply them (but don't forget to initialize `extend1` with `1` instead of `0`):

```
function multiply1() {
    var extend1 = 1;                                           // <--changed here
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "1_value"+i;
        extend1 = extend1 * document.getElementById(id).value; // <--changed here
    }
    document.getElementById("extend1").value = extend1;
}
```

So the least traumatic way is doing this from `multiply1()` to `multiply5()`.

> Ok so first I need to multiply the Qty and Price boxes and secondly I need to figure out why this script isn't getting the value from the ext boxes after they are input from the Qty and Price script

Your `summate()` isn't being called because it is **hooked on the "`onInput`"** event of the `extendN` inputs. And you are changing the `extendN` with:

```
document.getElementById("extend1").value = extend1;
```

Which **does not trigger** the `onInput` event.

Quickest solution? After setting `extendN`'s values, call `summate()`. Here's the **final** verison:

```
function multiply1() {
    var extend1 = 1;                                           // <--changed here
    for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
        var id = "1_value"+i;
        extend1 = extend1 * document.getElementById(id).value; // <--changed here
    }
    document.getElementById("extend1").value = extend1;
    summate();                                                 // <--changed here
}
```

Here's a demo with the proposed changes: http://jsfiddle.net/zNFV8/

Comment: Thanks acdcjunior this works perfect for me, I had actually tried everything you did except changing the var extend1 = 0 to 1. Your answer helps me a great deal, I'm kind of upset that someone down voted my question by saying there is no research effort when I've been working on this for weeks and search through countless tutorials and examples with no success. I think this rating system is worthless!

Answer (score 2):

```
function multiply1() {
    var qty = document.getElementById('1_value1').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('1_value2').value;
    if (qty && price) {
        var total = qty * price;
        document.getElementById("extend1").value = total;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("extend1").value = '';
    }
}
```

There's also no need to have 5 different `multiplyN` functions. Write one function that takes `N` as a parameter, and figures out the IDs of the elements using that.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I couldn't figure out how to get my current script to total from row to row so did what I knew would work at the time, It's easier for me to learn by example than to read through a ton of tutorials that don't really show me what I'm trying to do this helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that might help. It works on my local box, but I cant get it to work in jsfiddle :/

HTML Code

```
<label for = "price"> Price </label>
<input name="price" type = "text" id="price" />

<br />

<label for = "quantity"> Quantity </label>
<input name="quantity" type = "text" id="quantity" />

<br />

<label for = "total"> Total</label>  
<input name ="total" type = "text" id = "total" />
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("quantity").setAttribute("onkeyup", 'calculateTotal()');
document.getElementById("price").setAttribute("onkeyup", 'calculateTotal()');

function calculateTotal() {
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
  var quantity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);

if (price * quantity == parseFloat(price * quantity))
    document.getElementById("total").value = price * quantity;
else
    document.getElementById("total").value = '';
}
```

CSS

```
 label {width: 100px;  float: left;}
```

Comment: Thanks user, every thing is helpful since I'm just learning JavaScript!